# Top 10 dangerous mistakes in C programming?

Tags: known-vulnerabilities, c, software, secure-coding

What is the top dangerous mistakes in C programming?

for example misusing a `strcpy` causes a stack-overflow and code injection.

I'm looking for at least 10 bad programming pattern in C.

Comment: Not knowing what you are doing is No.1. Flagging to close as a bad subjective.

Comment: I'm looking for a top ten of risky mistakes in C? what do yo want to know more? I'm a C developer and i want to avoid them.

Comment: My list http://www.andromeda.com/people/ddyer/topten.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the best way to learn the answer to this question is reading a lot of book and doing best practies. I advice you this book [Secure Coding in C and C++](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780321822130/samplepages/0321822137.pdf)  to all topic about secure coding in c.

Answer (score 4):

The topmost dangerous mistake in C programming is **using C**. This is an unpopular assertion, but decades of experience back me up.

C is a nice programming language in that it allows you to express operations in an "abstract machine" (that's how the C standard puts it) which will get translated efficiently into machine code (the translation tools runs fast *and* the result is fast). However, this translation comes at a high price, namely that they are no safeguard for mistakes, and there are a lot of "undefined behaviours" lurking in the shadows. [Pointer aliasing rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing), for instance, are almost never understood correctly, leading to seemingly good code which will fail (sometimes in ways which create exploitable vulnerabilities) when a newer compiler is used or an optimization switch activated.

Looking for a "list of mistake" is the wrong mindset. You want a blacklist: things to avoid, under the assumption that "everything else" is safe. You should want a **whitelist**: a list of *allowed* ways to develop, at the exclusion of everything else. Successful C programmers are programmers who are able to maintain their own discipline to *never* use any construction that they do not master from end-to-end; and by "mastering" I mean the ability to describe how the C compiler will translate that into assembly opcodes, including all the possible optimizations that C compilers are allowed to make.

A good way to "use C" is to write the one or two routines which really need speed in some optimized C, and the rest of the code in a safer language which will allow for faster, easier and *safer* development (e.g. Python, C#, Node.js, Perl... the choice is large).

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the [CWE/SANS Top 25 Most Dangerous Software Errors](http://cwe.mitre.org/top25/index.html). This is for software development in general (independent of programming language) but also includes errors made in C/C++.